# Missing email on Elastic Beanstalk Environment Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS SNS to receive environment notifications from my application on AWS beanstalk. The connection works but only some of the events are reported. Like if there is a health issue or configuration is changed, I got an email immediately but if the server is restarted or code redeployed, I got no nothing. I have no idea why only some of the events could trigger the email.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Sure, I am receiving email. Just not any events will be reported to me. It drives me crazy.